# How to create mex files for libsvm C files

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I have dowloaded `libsvm` from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/
I unziped and copied the `libsvm` folder to `c:..../documents/MATLAB` folder. included`mex.h` to all C files. Inside libsvm-> I have different folders. also in that Matlab folder I have files like `libsvmread.c` , `libsvmwrite.c` , `makefile`, `make.m`, `svmtrain` ,`svmpredict` etc...

how I can use these files in matlab? Can any one help me to create .mex files for these files.
I read and tried many times ..it is not working correctly for me. I need to do svmensemble creation in `matlab.can` anyone help me ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **README** file:

> ## Installation and Data Format
>
> On Unix systems, type `make' to build the`svm-train' and
>   `svm-predict' programs. Run them without arguments to show the usages
>   of them.
>
> On other systems, consult `Makefile' to build them (e.g., see
>   'Building Windows binaries' in this file) or use the pre-built
>   binaries (Windows binaries are in the directory`windows').

For more information, tell us which operating system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do mex -setup to configure the compiler.After which, you run the make.m file in the matlab folder.. Please read the README file.. the details are there...